# run Xcode via applescript(osascript)

Tags: ios, xcode, vim, applescript

- OSX Yosemite
- Xcode 7.1

i'm developing iOS by vim or atom.
but there is thing i don't like.
must press command + tab and then switch to Xcode when wanna run.

i found this script that resolution this problem. but it doesn't work well.

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        perform (keystroke "r" using command down)
    end tell
end tell
```

or another applescript. it doesn't work too.

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate

    set targetProject to project of active workspace document
    if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
        launch targetProject
    end if
end tell
```

PLZ HELP.

Answer (score 2):

The first script is almost correct, just `perform` is wrong syntax

```
activate application "Xcode"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Xcode"
        keystroke "r" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: It's the same behavior as pressing ⌘R in Xcode physically. You could combine both scripts by sending the `build` command, waiting for completion and press run.